# How to PuTTY into a VirtualBox VM with a NAT network adapter?

Tags: virtualbox, putty

So, I am not sure what IP address to put in PuTTY so that I can SSH to the guest vm from the host; the VM is configured with the connection type NAT.

Comment: Very similar question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537751/virtualbox-port-forward-from-guest-to-host

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the address of the host, e.g. 127.0.0.1 if you are on that machine. You will need to set up port forwarding in VirtualBox, which can be found in the networking settings:

[image]

Set up the rule using whatever host port you want (as long as it doesn't conflict with another service on the host), and whatever your guest IP and port values are, for example:

[image]

(If you leave the host IP field blank, you will be able to access the guest from any machine on your LAN.) Then you can ssh to your local IP on the specified host port, and the traffic will be forwarded to the port you specified on the guest.

For more information, see [the documentation](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat).

Comment: Or leave IP's blanks

Answer (score 0):

The VM's IP address on its primary network adaptor.

Your host is going to actually create a NAT network, which your host should have a virtual adaptor on. So, you can use whatever `ifconfig` or `ipconfig` tells you as the address for the guest.

I should point out that this is going to be the case as long as the guest has networking; with VirtualBox there should always be an adaptor on the host that can talk to the guest network.